# Laravel Passport Vue components do not be published in the correct path

Tags: laravel, npm, vuejs2, laravel-passport, laravel-5.7

According to [**Frontend Quickstart**](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/passport#frontend-quickstart) official documentation of [laravel-5.7](/questions/tagged/laravel-5.7). I run the command:

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=passport-components
```

I have no any error messages, it returns:

> Copied Directory
>
> [/vendor/laravel/passport/resources/assets/js/components] To
>   [/resources/assets/js/components/passport]
>
> Publishing complete.

So, it does not copied to `resources/js/components` like the documentation stated:

> The published components will be placed in your
>   resources/js/components directory.

I don't know why does it published in different path other than specified in the documentation? and how could I solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In 5.7 the `resources/assets/js` directory became `resources/js` which has been causing issues.

There is an open issue about this on the passport github page: https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/829